# Junk character getting displayed for Korean when ucnv_convert() is used

Tags: c++, icu

I am using ibus keyboard for my application to input Korean characters.
I am entering a person's name in the first,middle,last format.
Now, when i do a conversion from "EUC-KR" to "UTF-8" using ucnv_convert()
The middle name is displayed as a box character.
Following is my code

```
    void convert(unsigned char * in, unsigned int inLen, char *from, char *to)
    {
        unsigned char *inbuff = in;
        char *pout = NULL;
        int outBuffLen = inLen*4;
        UErrorCode  ErrorCode = U_ZERO_ERROR;
        pout = new char [outBuffLen +1];
        memset(pout,0, outBuffLen );
        int size = ucnv_convert(to, from, pout,outBuffLen, (const char *) inbuff, inLen, &ErrorCode );

    }
```

Input Characterset: EUC-KR (using ibus keyboard)
OutPut: UTF-8

if the word "middle" (in Korean) is converted it always gives me box characters.
Please help

Comment: Could you clarify what the word in Korean actually is? Also is `pout` used after being converted? Is the function incomplete? How did you know it gives you box characters?

Comment: Where do you check `ErrorCode` to see if there was an error using `ucnv_convert()`?

Comment: @MujjinGun the word is 읻. Yes the function is incomplete. When I try to print pout using std::cout, it gives the box character for the above character.

Comment: @MujjinGun when I type middle using Korean keyboard I get ㅡㅑㅇ읻 But after UTF-8 conversion 읻 character is replaced with a box

Comment: If your terminal is using euc-kr and you try to print utf-8, I wouldn't expect it to render properly.

Comment: @MujjinGun. Could you please check my below comments and help me out?  I changed my source encoding to CP949 and tried. Now after UTF-8 conversion, I do not see the box character. But "middle" is displayed as "ㅡ야솻" instead of "ㅡㅑㅇ읻". Is it the correct translation?

Answer (score 2):

"읻" cannot be represented in EUC-KR. It isn't in the "common 2350 syllable" list. It can, however, be represented in CP949, which is Microsoft's backwards-compatible extension to EUC-KR. When people say "EUC-KR" they usually mean CP949. So I suggest you to try that instead.

Comment: @MujjnGun Thanks for your suggestion. I changed my source encoding to CP949 and tried. Now after UTF-8 conversion, I do not see the box character. But "middle" is displayed as "ㅡ야솻" instead of "ㅡㅑㅇ읻". Is it the correct translation?

Comment: Hi @MujjinGun, could you please help me with the above query?